# $\prod A_\lambda$ is closed proof

Tags: general-topology

> Given a topological product $\prod X_{\lambda}$ and $A_{\lambda}\subset X_{\lambda}$ subspaces of $X_{\lambda}$. Prove the product of closed sets $A_{\lambda}$ is closed.

I tried to prove this in the following way.

Consider an arbitrary $x\in\prod X_{\lambda}$ and $x_{u}\in X_{u}$ in which $u\in\lambda$. I am going to prove the complement is open $x_{\lambda}\notin A_{\lambda},\:\forall \lambda$. As $A_{\lambda}$ is assumed closed, then if $U_\lambda$ is the neighbourhood of $x_\lambda$, then $U_u\cap A_u=\emptyset,\:u\in\lambda\:$.

Therefore $\prod U _{\lambda}\cap\prod A_\lambda=\prod(U_\lambda\cap A_\lambda)=\emptyset $(The product of the empty set is the empty set). So $(\prod A_\lambda)^c$ contains $U=\prod U _{\lambda}$ that is the neighbourhood of an arbitrary $x$. So $(\prod A_\lambda)^c$ is open which implies $(\prod A_\lambda)$ is closed.

I was told I should use $\prod \overline{A_\lambda}$ and $\overline{\prod A_\lambda}$. But I am not seeing how can I prove using the adherence.

Questions:

1)Is my proof right

2)How can I integrate $\prod \overline{A_\lambda}$ and $\overline{\prod A_\lambda}$ in my proof?

If my proof is wrong. Can someone provide one proof of the statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your notation is inconsistent. For $ \prod X_{\lambda}$ you should say $X=\prod_{\lambda \in S}X_{\lambda} $ for some (arbitrary) index-set $S.$ ....And  ask to prove that $\prod_{\lambda\in S}A_{\lambda}$ is closed in $X$ if $A_{\lambda}$  is closed in $X_{\lambda}$  for each $\lambda \in S.$... Further on you refer to $U_u$ and $A_u$ for $u\in \lambda,$  which is either inconsistent or meaningless..... It is also unclear what $U$ and  $U_{\lambda}$ are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first intuition of a proof was the following:

Let's denote the index set by $\Lambda$ and fix $\lambda_0 \in \Lambda$.

$A_{\lambda_0} \subset X_{\lambda_0}$ is closed, so $X_{\lambda_0} \setminus A_{\lambda_0} \subset X_{\lambda_0}$ is open.

By definition of the product topology on $X := \prod\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda} X_{\lambda}$, the set $(X_{\lambda_0} \setminus A_{\lambda_0}) \times \prod\limits_{\lambda \neq \lambda_0} X_{\lambda}$ is open in $X$.

So its complement $A_{\lambda_0} \times \prod\limits_{\lambda \neq \lambda_0} X_{\lambda}$ is closed in $X$.

The set $\prod\limits_{\lambda_0 \in \Lambda} A_{\lambda_0} = \bigcap\limits_{\lambda_0 \in \Lambda} \left( A_{\lambda_0} \times \prod\limits_{\lambda \neq \lambda_0} X_{\lambda} \right)$ is closed in $X$ as an intersection of closed sets.

Using closures will essentially lead to the same argument.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, the openness of $(X_{\lambda_0} \setminus A_{\lambda_0}) \times \prod\limits_{\lambda \neq \lambda_0} X_{\lambda} = \pi_{\lambda_0}^{-1} \left( X_{\lambda_0} \setminus A_{\lambda_0} \right)$ comes from the fact, that the product topology is defined by requiring the projections onto the factors to be continuous: The product topology is the smallest (coarsest) topology containing all preimages of open sets under projections.

Warning: Infinite products of open sets are not open in general.

Comment: Perfectly right.

Comment: I might be wrong. Here$(X_{\lambda_0} \setminus A_{\lambda_0}) \times \prod\limits_{\lambda \neq \lambda_0} X_{\lambda}$ I guess
 you are already using the statement I wanted to prove, by stating that the product of two open sets is open.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet What do you think?

Comment: @PedroGomes the openness of the sets is the product topology definition.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Can the statement be proven without the product topology definition? My idea was to prove that the Cartesian product of arbitrary closed sets is closed, without the need to refer to a topology.  By the way thanks for your answers!

Comment: @PedroGomes of course you need to use the topology! How else is “closed” defined?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So first you need to state that $B=\prod_\lambda B_\lambda\in\tau$, for$ B\subset X$ and  $(X,\tau)$ topological space? So that you know by definition the product of two open sets is open.

Comment: @PedroGomes. There is more than one type of product topology. The Tychonoff product topology is definaable as the weakest topology for which each of the projections $\pi_{\lambda}:\prod_{\lambda\in S}X_{\lambda}\to X_{\lambda}$ is continuous, which is the topology in this Q.

Answer (score 2):

All $\pi_\lambda$ are continuous maps. So inverse images of closed sets are closed.

So $$\prod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_\lambda = \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} (\pi_\lambda)^{-1}[A_\lambda]$$

which is an intersection of closed sets so closed.

Comment: Just one question I have been wondering for a long while. I have never understood why is not enough to write$ (\pi_\lambda)^{-1}[A_\lambda]$ instead of$\bigcap_\lambda (\pi_\lambda)^{-1}[A_\lambda]$ Why is the intersection needed?

Comment: @PedroGomes your notation makes no sense. I’m assuming that $\lambda$ is the index, and that there is some unspoken set (say $A$ e.g.) they belong to. So $\prod_{\lambda} A_\lambda$ is short for $\prod_{\lambda \in A} X_\lambda$. But you seem to use $\lambda$ as the index set and $u$ for its elements, so you ought to write $\prod_{u \in \lambda} X_u$ instead.

Comment: @PedroGomes $\pi_\lambda^{-1}[A_\lambda]$ is just the inverse image of *one* closed set (namely of index $\lambda$). But the product is defined so that it holds for *all* indices. Hence the intersection.